# Обособление причастного оборота при перестановке слов

Tags: запятые, причастный-оборот

*Автора я имел в виду, написавшего в теме.*

Можно было начать "я имел в виду автора...", тогда запятая точно нужна, потому что причастный оборот идёт сразу после определяемого слова. Но ведь и при моей перестановке запятая всё равно не отпадает, верно?

Comment: Тут (при Вашей перестановке) пауза побольше требуется, — не иначе как тире. Только оно способно связать оборот с Автором.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь нужна не запятая, а знаки, отделяющие пояснение, произнесённое вдогонку (тире или скобки), - имеющийся порядок слов оправдан только при документальном воспроизведении устной речи (со значением: я действительно имел в виду *автора*, и это тот, кто написал в теме). С запятой же это воспринимается как лексическая ошибка (вместо "под автором я имел в виду написавшего").

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Значит, не нужна всё-таки запятая. Вы всё правильно поняли!

Answer (score 1):

Верно, только это выражение не является литературной нормой, это разговорный вариант. Кто-то сочтёт и  грамматической ошибкой.

Comment: Тем более, что в современной лексике, подобное построение фразы образует некий другой смысл, не разговорный, а "дворовый" арго, с ярко выраженным извращением смысла выражения "иметь в виду".

Comment: Спасибо! Где же, @romandc, извращение смысла?

Comment: Насчёт разговорного всё правильно, это из простой переписки типа чата.

Comment: @Артём Луговой К сожалению,среди молодых и неокрепших, некоторые слова приобрели устойчивый негативный смысл. "Голубой", например. Или "Мать". Это наша вина, и мы несём за это полную ответственность. Когда-то я перевёл одну фразу почти дословно: "Какое счастье иметь таких Сестёр…", и неожиданно получил за это целый вал комментариев с негативом. Слово "иметь" у подавляющего большинства прочно ассоциировалось с сексуальным подтекстом. А "иметь в виду" на дворовом сленге может означать резкое неприятие оппонента.

Comment: По крайней мере я ничего такого под "иметь в виду" не имел в виду. :))